# What to do with duplicates with no answers?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The question [*What is proper time for drinking water with meal?*](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/what-is-proper-time-for-drinking-water-with-meal) was asked yesterday, and in essence it asks the same thing as the question [*Drinking water during or after Meal*](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/drinking-water-during-or-after-meal?rq=1), asked over 6 months ago. The problem is, that the older question got only one answer, which received downvotes due to lack of reputable references.

The new question, although a good one, has already got one bad answer (without references). We might get into a similar situation again, because we have a substantial amount of unanswered questions.

My question is: what do we do with the new question, both in this case and in general? Mark and close it as a duplicate, let it stand or let it stand and point out in comments that there is another (answerless) question dealing with the same issues?

Comment: This is [a problem network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933/272257), and I've never seen a well work-out solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question can only be closed as a duplicate to another if that other question had an upvoted or accepted answer. So the best we can do in my opinion is leave a comment, and when one of the questions gets answered, the other can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Leave a comment to the new question or to both of them cross-referencing the other?

Comment: @Lucky commenting on one is at least enough to get them to show up as related questions. But both is probably better so that if one gets an answer, hopefully someone will remember to close the other as a duplicate?